# SQL Delete Statement does not work with selecting a row from a dataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am trying to delete a selected row from a DataGridView which is linked to a Table in the database. Its stating the following error code.

[image]

Any ideas with where i am going wrong here?

***Delete Button Code***

```
private void DeleteExtraBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        //Delete selected extra row    
        SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("Delete From Extra Where Extra_ID = @Extra_ID", con);
        sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExtraID", extraGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0]);
        sda.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }


    con.Close();
    loadExtraTable();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see you executing the command anywhere.

Add;

```
sda.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also you are referencing the cell object and not its value.
Also, you reference `@ExtraID` and `@Extra_ID`

```
private void DeleteExtraBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        //Delete selected extra row    
        SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("Delete From Extra Where Extra_ID = @ExtraID", con);
        sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExtraID", extraGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
        sda.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }


    con.Close();
    loadExtraTable();
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, apologies. I didnt include it in the example above. But its still not working with this.

Comment: You should for matters of good practice wrap your connection and commands in using blocks to allow for easier cleanup. Have you checked that the con is opening? If it does not open it will not alwayse throw an error.

Comment: Showing the error that i have just added to the code above.

Comment: looks like you may be trying to add the cell object and not the cell objects value, should look somthign closer to `extraGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value` or `extraGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Text`

Comment: Good point, it needs value. Im getting an error to declare the scalar variable for @Extra_ID

Comment: You have a varible naming mismatch `@Extra_ID` != `@ExtraID`

Comment: I feel so silly. Im so tired, need a rest. Im starting to make silly mistakes. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

What is "ExtraId", a textbox, a string?

Depending on that, you have to use:

```
SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("Delete From Extra Where Extra_ID = @" + Extra_ID.Text, con);
```